# Does Heroku no longer support Celery?

Tags: python, heroku, celery, amqp

I was finally getting to the point where I had some free time and wanted to add Celery to my Python/Flask project on Heroku. However, almost all mentions of Celery from the Heroku docs are gone. There used to be article with a tutotial in the "Getting started with Django", but it's gone.

Will "just doing it" myself work? What's a good AMQP addon to use as backend on Heroku?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I'm the owner of Python at Heroku.

Celery is still fully supported. The documentation at the bottom of the Django guide was removed because it was out of date with the latest release of Celery (v3.0) and was fairly incomplete, in my opinion.

I'm currently working on a new [Dev Center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku) that goes in depth on how to get the most out of Celery. It should be posted soon.

As for the queue addon — I'm a big fan of [CloudAMPQ](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudamqp).

Comment: Looking forward to seeing this Kenneth!

Comment: It must be a very, very long article, when you're working on it since march.

Comment: Any word on that article or support for celery on heroku?

Comment: How about that article?

Comment: I can't find any documentation currently to use Celery on Heroku.

Comment: It's possible that Kenneth died and the article got buried with him o_O

Comment: Is this the new Dev Center celery article? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudamqp#celery

Answer (score 3):

They seem to have changed the docs. Not sure celery is not supported anymore, since its simply a python package and you could just install it.

Here is the documentation on [how to get started with Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) (without the part where celery was mentioned last time I watched it). They seem to use RQ now to do what celery did before: [Background Tasks in Python with RQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq). You might still find something regarding celery [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudamqp), but that's all I found.

Generally I doubt that celery is simply removed. It would affect all other apps which already have something set up with Celery. I think you can still make it work and might find some articles away from the Heroku docs.

Comment: I found the same references. The references to Celery in the other remaining Heroku docs are not really helpful, and barely exist actually.

Of course Celery is just a package and I could it myself, but they removed the doc, changed another Python doc to menion only rq, and removed a plugin (I think there used to be a plugin). It makes me think like they discovered an issue that made it not work, not removed it voluntarily.

I searched, but couldn't find outside tutorials. I will search some more.

Comment: The example they had for celery was terrible though, it used the database broker for one, so I wouldn't be surprised if someone experienced problems (using the db is not recommended)

Comment: why isn't it recommended to use the db from Celery?

Comment: It's not recommended to use the database as a broker (results are fine).  The database backend does not work well with multiple worker instances, it was written for testing and development environments.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are issues with Celery as a background task on Heroku. We tried to create such tasks and they take all memory after running for about 20 minutes, even with DEBUG=False on Redis or RabbitMQ. Worse still, the memory is NEVER released: every time we have to restart the worker. 
The same code runs flawlessly on bare Linux or on Mac with Foreman.
It happens with very simple tasks, like reading a text file in a loop, writing to a Django model.

Comment: This is my experience even in 2019.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it took me way long than I'd like to admit to figure out how to make this work, it is really pretty straight forward. In your procfile, add a celery process. It'll look something like this:

```
web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn -w 4 myapp.wsgi
celery: python manage.py celeryd -c 3 --beat
```

Then, just make sure to scale the celery dyno to at least 1:

```
heroku ps:scale celery=1
```

That's all.

Comment: Hi Josh - could you write a more detailed blog post about this.  I'll pay you $100.

Comment: Feel free to contact me off site to discuss. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We do fully support celery on Heroku. You can run workers on my naming your worker processes and scaling them, and run any process. In terms of what to use as a backend we have a variety of add-on providers which can support this via Rabbit, Redis, or others.

You can find a full guide within devcenter at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku.